# Ansible create directories from a list

Tags: loops, variables, dictionary, ansible

I want to create some directories from a list I have in my `vars/main.yml`.

```
- app_root:
    network_prod:   "/var/www/prod/network/app"
    database_prod:  "/var/www/prod/db/app"
```

My `tasks/main.yml` so far has this:

```
- name: Create application directory structure
  file: 
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 755
  with_items:
    - app_root
```

but doesn't work. I thought this could be achieved using `with_dict` and I also tried:

```
- name: Create application directory structure
  file: 
    path: "{{ item.value }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 755
  with_dict:
    - app_root
```

but I got: `fatal: [vagrant.dev] => with_dict expects a dict`.

I've read all about [looping-over-hashes](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-hashes), but this doesn't seem to work.

The reason I'm using this notation is because I use these variables elsewhere as well and I need to know how to call them.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find it a bit easier to convert yaml to json to make sure I'm understanding it properly.  Take your example:

```
- app_root:
    network_prod:   "/var/www/prod/network/app"
    database_prod:  "/var/www/prod/db/app"
```

What you have here is not a list, but a nested dictionary.  If you converted this to json it would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "app_root": {
      "network_prod": "/var/www/prod/network/app",
      "database_prod": "/var/www/prod/db/app"
    }
  }
]
```

In order to loop through this in Ansible you would need to dereference two levels of a dictionary, the first being `app_root` and the second being the path elements.  Unfortunately I don't think Ansible supports looping through nested dictionaries, only through nested loops.

Your best bet is probably to redo the way you're defining your paths so that you're not creating as complex a data structure. If all you're doing in this case is iterating over a list of paths in order to ensure the directories exist then I'd suggest something like this in your `vars/main.yml` file:

```
network_prod:   "/var/www/prod/network/app"
database_prod:  "/var/www/prod/db/app"

app_root:
  - network_prod
  - database_prod
```

Then you can have a task like this:

```
file: path={{ item }}
      state=directory 
with_items: app_root
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to what you suggested. I just had to quote the list items:

    app_root:
      - "{{ network_prod }}"
      - "{{ database_prod }}"

Answer (score 0):

In `vars/main.yml`, try removing the dash in front of `app_root`.

```
app_root:
  network_prod:   "/var/www/prod/network/app"
  database_prod:  "/var/www/prod/db/app"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the approach with `with_dict` was correct and I believe that the only issue here is the dash `-` in front of `app_root` variable. Instead of:

```
- name: Create application directory structure
  file: 
    path: "{{ item.value }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 755
  with_dict:
    - app_root
```

It should be:

```
- name: Create application directory structure
  file: 
    path: "{{ item.value }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 755
  with_dict: app_root
```

See the difference on the way the variable `app_root` is passed to `with_dict`.

A dash in YAML starts a list and the elements are not treated as variables but as literals, think of it as if you were passing an immutable string 'app_root' to `with_dict`  (not exactly true but it helps me to think it this way) so `when_dict` fails to parse it because it is given a list instead of the expected dictionary. However, without a dash, `with_dict` is populated with the variable `app_root` instead and it will parse it without issues.